# Canceling CountDownTimer doesn't work in onPause() if resuming timer in onResume()

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer, onresume, onpause

I'm trying to cancel timer in `onPause()` and resume it in `onResume()`, but canceling doesn't work. Timer still works in background. Does anybody know why?

```
    var currentMillis: Long = 0

            // First creation of your timer
            var timer = object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

                    currentMillis = millisUntilFinished // <-- save value

                    textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
                    println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                }

                override fun onFinish() {}
            }

        override fun onPause() {
                super.onPause()
                timer.cancel()


            }
            override fun onResume() {
                super.onResume()


                timer = object : CountDownTimer(currentMillis, 1000) {
                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                        currentMillis = millisUntilFinished
                        textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
                        println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                    }

                    override fun onFinish() {}
                }
                timer.start()

            }

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app)



timer.start()
```

Edited:

```
var i = 0
    if (i == 0) {
        timer = object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                currentMillis = millisUntilFinished
                textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
                println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {}
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = object : CountDownTimer(currentMillis, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            currentMillis = millisUntilFinished
            textView3.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
            println("Timer  : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {}
    }
    }

    timer?.start()
    i++
```

Comment: When `timer = object : CountDownTimer` runs in `onResume()`, you are clobbering an existing reference: the one you created at module scope. That one continues running, even though you have lost the reference to it. It will eventually get GC'd, but not until it reaches the end of the countdown.

Comment: Thanks, for answer. Is there any workaround for this using `onResume()`?

Comment: Have you considered simply eliminating the timer at module scope?

Comment: Is module scope onResume()? If I delete this part https://imgur.com/a/iQUmd0J timer on resume again starts from 60000 milliseconds.

Comment: No, I was referring to the first timer, not the second one.

Comment: If I delete timer from module scope, I have to create separate instances of timer in all inner scopes and I can't pause and resume the same timer from different scopes. What do you mean?

Comment: You can still _declare_ the `timer` member variable. Just leave it as null. Do not _assign_ a value until `onResume()`. Do not attempt to use `timer` if it is null.

Comment: From what you are saying to me, I understand that I need place something like `var timer = object` to scope of class definition or I don't understand something. Then how to cancel it in `onPause()`?

Comment: Right, you should be able to do something like `var timer: CountDownTimer?` for the member variable. Your second question should answer itself.

Comment: Now timer doesn't start from 60s at all because it's null, so, how to start it? If I put `timer = object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000)...` to onCreate(), timer doesn't pause `onPause()`

Comment: I'm beginning to sense that this question is getting a little out of hand. To keep things simple, let's return to first principles. Could you state -- as precisely as you can -- exactly what you are trying to accomplish by running a timer in this way. Also, do you understand when `onResume()` is called, in relation to `onCreate()` and `onPause()`? And, after reading my first comment, do you fully understand why you had a timer "running out-of-control"?

Comment: Maybe not really. I think that first happens `onCreate()`, when I minimize, `onPause()`, after going back to app `onResume()` . Am I wrong?

Comment: I read your first comment. As I understand if I declare timer and then pause it I don't lose its reference, and it should be stopped. But I still have value that I can reach and use in `onResume()`. It's `currentMillis`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202990/discussion-between-greeble31-and-vasik988).